Visual Studio 2022

I have a problem with debugging in VS 2022. My program in C++ is reading data from file through standard input. The output is also written to file. I execute my programin BASH using command "./program<in.txt>out.txt". It generates wrong data and I would like to debug it in VS. Unfortunately I don't know how read file during debugging. I know that I can create program with fixed input data and then look for mistakes in code. Is it possible to debug it using data from file? 
Emdez

Interesting. Visual Studio 2022 doesn't run on any systems that typically run bash. Are you sure you don't accidentally get Visual Studio Code?

I use Git Bash as CMD.

Understood. Just had to make sure in case you were getting the tools mixed up.

See if this approach helps: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6021317/4581301

I understand you're seeking guidance on how to designate input files for debugging. Here's a straightforward approach that may be of help to you, and I trust it will facilitate your debugging process
Open your project: Ensure that your project is opened in Visual Studio.
• Set breakpoints: Set breakpoints in the code where you want the execution to pause so you can inspect variables.
• Configure startup options:
• Right-click on your project in the Solution Explorer.
• Select "Properties".
• Go to the "Debug" section.
• Set command line arguments : in.txt (set the file you want the program to read)
